# $ is not defined Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

При оценке $('.phone-details') в консоли элемент выводится, $ так же в консоли определен, но при клике на строку таблицы появляется ошибка ReferenceError: $ is not defined. Использую первый ангуляр, вроде там jQuery light встроена должна быть.
Код:

```js
let contactBook = angular.module('ContactBook',[]);

function randomInteger(min,max){
    return Math.floor(min + Math.random()*(max+1-min));
};

function generateNumber(){
    let prefixRange = [300,400];
    let keyRange = [0,100];
    let indexRange = [0,100];
    return `${randomInteger(...prefixRange)}-${randomInteger(...keyRange)}-${randomInteger(...indexRange)}`;
};

function MyListController($scope,$http) {
    $scope.persons = [
        {'name': 'Julie', 'number': generateNumber()},
        {'name': 'Peter', 'number': generateNumber()},
        {'name': 'Stephen', 'number': generateNumber()},
        {'name': 'Hpsuh', 'number': generateNumber()},
        {'name': 'Daniele', 'number': generateNumber()},
        {'name': 'Elizabeth', 'number': generateNumber()},
        {'name': 'Cristine', 'number': generateNumber()}
    ];
    $scope.showDetails = function(person){
        var index = $scope.persons.indexOf(person);
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sakuranasty/detailstemplates/master/'+(index+1)+'.html'
        }).then(function(response){
            $('.phone-details').innerHTML = response.data; // посмотреть директиву для вставки html
        },
        function(){
            $('.phone-details').innerHTML = 'FAILED TO LOAD DETAILS';
        });
    };

};
contactBook.controller('MyListController', ['$scope','$http', MyListController]);
```

разметка:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="ContactBook">
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">
        <title>Phone catalog</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/styles/style.css">
        <script src="src/scripts/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="src/scripts/app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="MyListController">
        <div class="wrap">
            <form class="input-form" action="#" >
                <input type="text" ng-model="query"><!--c маленькой буквой,т.к. property-->
            </form>
            <div class="phone-directory">
                <div class="phone-table">
                    <table >
                        <tr><th>Photo</th></th><th>Name</th><th>Phone</th></tr>
                        <tr ng-repeat="person in persons | filter:query"  ng-click="showDetails(person)">
                            <td>{{$index + 1}}</td><td><img class="icon" src="src/svg/question.svg" alt=""></td><td>{{person.name}}</td><td>{{person.number}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="phone-details">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: JQ light действительно встроена в ангуляр, но доступна через `angular.element`, а не через `$`. Ну и прямая манипуляция DOM - это не angular way. Есть же `ng-include`, например, или `ng-bind-html`, на худой конец.

Comment: интересно то, что в консоли $ доступен, и $(selector) тоже определяется

Comment: В консоли по крайней мере Хрома - да, `$` определен даже на совершенно пустой странице (`<html></html>`), это, по-видимому, фича консоли Хрома.

Comment: пишите так: angular.element('.phone-details').

Comment: @Konst К сожалению так не получится, поиск по селектору такая запись не позволяет. воспользовалась советом документации использовать стандарный `document.querySelector`. Из документации (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element): `Note: Keep in mind that this function will not find elements by tag name / CSS selector. For lookups by tag name, try instead angular.element(document).find(...) or $document.find(), or use the standard DOM APIs, e.g. document.querySelectorAll().`

Comment: Обернула элемент в JQLite как `angular.element(document.querySelector('.phone-details))`. Это мне нужно было для того, чтобы вызвать $compile

Answer (score 0):

воспользовалась советом документации использовать стандарный `document.querySelector`. Для данного примера я получила нужное мне поведение. Далее мне нужно было данный html сделать частью ангуляра, т.е. скомпилировать. Для этого нужно вызвать сервис $compile, который принимает в качестве аргумента объект JQLite. Превратить его в JQLite можно с помощью `angular.element(document.querySelector('.phone-details))`.

Answer (score -3):

Попробуйте установить jquery плагин для ангулара

```
npm install jquery --save
```

А сверу в app.module.ts потом добавьте

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
```

Comment: Совет из разряда "никогда так не делайте".